# Is it bad practice to use onPause() to capture user-entered data in Android programming?

Tags: android, onpause, activity-lifecycle

I am writing an Android app that takes some information from the user from two editText fields a number picker. I've seen some ways on SO to collect this information dynamically (i.e. as the user enters it) but it seems to me that just calling the getter functions from onPause() would be much simpler.

The android Activity reference seems to imply that this type of programming is normal. Are there any important pitfalls to keep in mind when doing this? Would this code below be fine for my project?

```
public void editName() {
    name = textView.getText().toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    editName();
    //call other function to do something with name
}
```

Comment: This should be on Programmers SE, since it deals with concept, not actual programming problem. Or it could be on CodeReview, since your code is obviously working(though doesn't do anything at all).

Comment: why u needed to get it at onPause?

Comment: you want to save string and put it back to edittext when you open activity again. Is that right ?

Comment: The TextView will do that on its own, when you leave the activity and return back you'll find the value still in it, you should get the value of the edit after a submit/save action or something

Comment: I need to save the edits and add to a database.